# MacVim set as default text editor: How to set files to open in a new tab as opposed to a new window?

Tags: text, editor, default, tabs, macvim

I've set MacVim as my default text editor, and when I double click files it opens up a new window.  Is there a way to set it to open up in a new tab instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Preferences (under MacVim in the menubar) you can change the selection of the radio button "Open files from applications" from "in a new window" to "in the current window" and then select "with a tab for each file" from the drop-down menu below.

Comment: This doesn't work when using the mvim script from terminal, although the other answer by déo does.

Comment: That's true, but to be fair, it isn't what the questioner asked for either.

Answer (score 7):

You can also edit the `mvim` script and look for the `opts` definition. Change it to something like:

```
opts="--remote-tab"
```

or

```
opts="--remote-tab-silent"
```

or

```
opts="--remote-tab-wait"
```

Depending on your taste, of course... ;-)